# greek letters and times

Tags: greek, mathpazo, times

i'm using palatino and trying to take some greek letters from times or computer modern. i used this command.

```
\DeclareSymbolFont{greeksymbols}{OML}{ptm}{m}{it}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\pi}{\mathalpha}{greeksymbols}{25}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\chi}{\mathalpha}{greeksymbols}{31}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mu}{\mathalpha}{greeksymbols}{22}
```

but it gave nothing: no error and no different output. it gives the same result.

a minimal example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{sum}

% i added
%\DeclareSymbolFont{greeksymbols}{OML}{ztmcm}{m}{it}
%\DeclareMathSymbol{\pi}{\mathalpha}{greeksymbols}{25}.....
%in sum.sty file.

\begin{document}

$\alpha \pi \chi \mu \theta $

\end{document}
```

any suggestion?

Comment: and what packages do you use to use palatino?... I usually use mathpazo package.

Comment: the same package: mathpazo

Comment: You should use `\DeclareSymbolFont{greeksymbols}{OML}{ztmcm}{m}{it}` if you want the font used by `mathptmx`. Please make a MWE

Comment: @egreg i wrote that but the result is still the same.

Comment: i added also \AtBeginDocument{... but this time it gave an error command \pi already defined.

Comment: @mert That's why I asked for a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Comment: sorry i didn't noticed that. i added an example.

Comment: @mert Not MWE: what's the `sum` package?

Comment: sorry that is my own sty file and i added all commands like "\DeclareMathSymbol{\pi}{\mathalpha}{greeksymbols}{25}" in it. i also tried to write these commands in preamble but it didnt work.

Comment: @mert In my minimal example they do. The result is awful, by the way: those symbols absolutely don't mix with Palatino. You see it in [this picture](http://i.stack.imgur.com/megbG.png)

Comment: maybe the problem is about scientific wp. i just write to learn how to do. my main attempt is taking greek letters from pxfonts. it looks better with palatino but some properties of pxfonts isn't good to me. any way. thanks.

Comment: @mert You can try `\usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath}` instead of `pxfonts`: the fonts are (almost) the same, but the metrics have been improved. But I don't think you have the package, if you use SWP (a piece of software which I can't recommend).

Answer (score 3):

Making your example into an MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathpazo}

\DeclareSymbolFont{greeksymbols}{OML}{ptm}{m}{it}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\pi}{\mathalpha}{greeksymbols}{"25}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\chi}{\mathalpha}{greeksymbols}{"31}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mu}{\mathalpha}{greeksymbols}{"22}

\begin{document}

$\alpha \pi \chi \mu  \theta $

\end{document}
```

The clue is in the log file:

```
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for OML+ptm on input line 13.

(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/omlptm.fd
File: omlptm.fd 
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OML/ptm/m/it' in size <10> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OML/cmm/m/it' tried instead on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OML/ptm/m/it' in size <7.6> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OML/cmm/m/it' tried instead on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OML/ptm/m/it' in size <6> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OML/cmm/m/it' tried instead on input line 13.
```

which is basically telling you that the font you have requested is not available so LaTeX will substitute a fallback instead.

Investigating `omlptm.fd` tells you why the substitution is 'silent' and does not show in the regular output:

```
\DeclareFontShape{OML}{ptm}{m}{it}
   {<-> ssub * cmm/m/it}{}
```

What this does is tell LaTeX that when `OML/ptm/m/it` is requested, it should substitute `OML/cmm/m/it` silently i.e. without reporting the substitution as a warning/error in the console output.